# Can't connect to remote MySQL server

Tags: mysql

When I tried to connect the remote MySQL server by using command line `mysql -h <remote-ip> -u any_existing_users -p` or any other mysql client such as phpmyadmin, it didn't work and the error hint was

```
ERROR 2003 (HY000) Can't connect to MySQL server on '<remote-ip>' (61)
```

But, when I tried `ssh <remote-ip>` and connected the MySQL locally by `mysql -u root -p`, there is no problem.

Here is part of the user table(`SELECT User, Host FROM mysql.user;`):

```
+------------------+----------------+
| User             | Host           |
+------------------+----------------+
| root             | %              |
| other_users      | <remote-ip>    |
| root             | localhost      |
+------------------+----------------+
```

So, what's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Have you enable networking in your mysql server, please verify once more if not below are the steps by which you can do it

```
  Edit /etc/my.cnf, run:
  # vi /etc/my.cnf

  Once file opened, locate line that read as follows

  [mysqld] 
  Make sure line skip-networking is commented (or remove line) and add following line

  bind-address=YOUR-SERVER-IP
```

Comment: also check your IPtables should not be blocking mysql connection remotely.